# GWT project unable to load **.nocache.js in the default html file

Tags: gwt

Currently I am developing a GWT project by using GWT 2.4.0 in eclipse 3.7. I deploy the app inside Tomcat 7. It run perfectly for the past 2 months.

However, now I am running into a problem which I unable to trace the problem. Here is the source code for "welcomeGWT.html".

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the browser's rendering engine into
"Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration with a "Quirks Mode" doctype may
lead to some differences in layout.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='gwt:module' content='com.haircare101.cesapp.Main=com.haircare101.cesapp.Main'>
        <title>101 HairCare: Customer Excellence System</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript"  src="com.haircare101.cesapp.Main/com.haircare101.cesapp.Main.nocache.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As the tomcat started, I type the corresponding URL into browser and it shows me this page with no error (no error shows inside Tomcat log files). But it unable to direct me to the specified GWT Main Entry Point (I saw this source file when I can "View Source" of browser).

** I have no compilation error, no deployment error or no runtime error.

Can anybody tells me the reason why it stuck in this page? Many thanks and appreciate!

Cheers,
Ryan C.

Comment: Are there errors in your browser's console/developer tools? (either JS errors, or errors retrieving the needed files)

Comment: Try to run your application from Google Chrome for it may show you errors other web browsers won't

Comment: Thanks for advice ~ I saw following error inside the JavaScript Console (Google Chrome)...
<br/><br/>
Uncaught java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
(anonymous function)8B0B2BF935822EA071855520D60A5B14.cache.html:2179
gwtOnLoad8B0B2BF935822EA071855520D60A5B14.cache.html:2341
Bcom.haircare101.cesapp.Main.nocache.js:2
com_haircare101_cesapp_Main.onScriptLoadcom.haircare101.cesapp.Main.nocache.js:15
(anonymous function)
<br/><br/>
Does anyone able to show me what happen with the script? (I did not change the HTML or JavaScript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides using google chrome, enable [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to debug your javascript and find out what's wrong. Apparently you have an array acess problem.

Most probably, it is in your GWT entry point and not in javascript (don't forget that all the client package code is transformed into javascript)

Comment: I'm glad this solved your problem. Just out of curiosity, what was the problem?

Comment: Thanks! You just reminded me that the problem is coming from the entry point file! 

This problem has been resolved! appreciated.

Comment: The gwt entry point souce file has a line of code  
RootLayoutPanel.get().remove(0);  

I just replaced it with  
RootLayoutPanel.get().clear();